# Positivity of conditional expectations

Tags: conditional-expectation

I am trying to prove the well-known positivity property of conditional expectations. Namely,
$X$ being a random variable on a measure space $(\Omega,\cal{F},P)$ and $\cal{A}$ being a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\cal{F}$, the following implication holds.
$$ X \geq 0 \text{ a.s. } \Rightarrow E[X\mid\cal{A}] \geq 0 \text{ a.s. }$$

I try to prove this by contradiction. Suppose for some sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\cal{B}$, $P(\{E[X\mid\cal{B}] < 0 \}) >0$.
Then I have $$\int_{\{E[X\mid\cal{B}] < 0 \}}E[X\mid\cal{B}]\,dP < 0$$
But then, 
$$\int_{\{E[X\mid\cal{B}] < 0 \}}E[X\mid\cal{B}]\,dP =  \int_{\{E[X\mid\cal{B}] < 0 \}} X \,dP \geq 0$$
The last inequality holds due to the nonnegativity constraint on $X$. Here I have a contradiction so the proof is complete. But I feel like I missed something. Is this proof OK? Thanks.

Comment: Looks okay. But have you a good argument for what you conclude after "Then we have"?

Comment: @drhab My argument was this: Since $E[X\mid\cal{B}](\omega)$ is negative over $\{\omega : E[X\mid\cal{B}](\omega) < 0 \}$, integrating it over these "events" should give something negative since probability measure is nonnegative.

Comment: That's true but it needs some argumentation. If $P(Y<0)>0$ then it can be shown that some $\epsilon>0$ exists such that $P(Y<-\epsilon)>0$. That is a step in between.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you very much.